# JAXWS-RI breaks XML Digital Signature

Tags: soap, jaxb

I've been all stuck for several days with a simple procedure

I am trying to digitally sign  some XML Document and then add it to a jaxb element so I can send it in soap message.
I am able to set jaxb element values, marshal it and sign it.
When it comes to unmarshalling back again I face a problem, I get an error:

```
DefaultValidationEventHandler: [FATAL_ERROR]: unexpected element (uri:"http://someuri",  
local:"SomeObject"). Expected elements are <someuri#DifferentObject}
```

Acording to the error "Expected elements" happen to be the XML digital Signature(child element of my main jaxb)

To fix this I add
    @XmlRootElement(name = "SomeObject") 
to my jaxb class Model and it unmarshals with no problems, however the namespace of DigitalSignature node(child element) is moved upwards. This is wrong because my XML digital signature is broken and even worse when I send soap message, the namespace is moved upper in the wrapper class so original signed Data is totally different. 
Question is how Can I avoid namespaces relocation in jaxb and JAXWS-RI/2.2.6?